# Some strange set notations used in mathematical texts.

Tags: soft-question, notation

In some kind of old mathematical text, writers use notations like following.

[image]

I guess at the left side it is written as "G".

My question is where can I find a list that contains that kind of notations?

Comment: I think this is a gothic G, $\mathfrak{G}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackletter. In LaTeX, it's fraktur. For instance, `\mathfrak G` is printed $\mathfrak G$. The other symbols come from group theory: [isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_isomorphism) and [semidirect product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product). If you want a list, look for a LaTeX guide.